# How to delete the app Data Folder from target Machine after program is uninstalled

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nsis, delete-file

I have created the electron app it creates the folder .name_of_folder when user install the software but when the user uninstalls the program I want to delete the folder how can do this in electron framework using nodeJs as backend

I am creating the folder from fs module

**how can i delete the .name_of_folder from target machine**

Comment: You are trying to delete it through code?  What is your stack?

Comment: Let me know your target OS and where this .name_of_foler has been placed.

Comment: yes through code @Nelles on uninstalling the program

Comment: @tpikachu the os i am targeting is Linux and window and .name_of_folder is placed in os.homeDir()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/) then you have two solution

**First option:**

Set `deleteAppDataOnUninstall = false` Boolean - one-click installer only. Whether to delete app data on uninstall.

```
"build": {
    "nsis": {
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true
    }
 }
```

**Second option:**

Custom NSIS script with `customUnInstall` macro

create `uninstaller.nsh` and put in `package.json` in `build` key

```
!macro customInstall
  RMDir /r "$APPDATA\${APP_PACKAGE_NAME}"
!macroend
```

```
"build": {
    "nsis": {
      "include": "installer.nsh"
    }
  }
```

Reference: https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#custom-nsis-script